# How make mandatory field inactive in vTiger?

Tags: php, sql, vtiger

I am working on a project in vTiger(mainly concentrating on leads module). In that I want to disable to fields 'Created Time' and 'Modified Time', but it seems that I am not able to do so. I have managed to disable mandatory fields such as 'Lastname', 'Firstname' and 'Assigned To'(but I can not hide those fields).

I disabled those fields by changing the [UItypes](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/510:UI_Types) in vtiger_fields table.

Can anyone please help me on this one(to disable/hide fields: 'Created Time' and 'Modified       Time' in leads module)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: seriously guys please help

Comment: Would changing the view/edit/create under roles hide it? Thats what I did on mine in Ver 6.  I hid created, allowed the view modified date.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, how do I check that?

Comment: In the CRM Settings (top right) ...left side nav, choose User & Access Control then  SharingAccess.  Click the arrow to the right of the module that you want...the fields appear, select view.   You can be more specific with who can it by defining roles in the same area

Comment: Hey thanks for that I will check it out & let you know

Comment: Hey zzipper72 appreciate your help thanks man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't change the presence column, because you need those fields to write times into the database (needed for history for example, because if you change it, you will always get 'created 44 years ago', because no 'Created Time' would be written into the database).

Instead, change the displaytype column to 4. This way the Time columns won't be shown, while dates will still be written into the database tables. (You can google for an explanation of all displaytype options - there are 4 options.)

Answer (score 1):

Hello you must go to vtiger_field find e.x Product Name AND in column presence from 2 make it 1 and thats it field Product Name is inactive.

Comment: Thanks Mathias that did the job